# Android Live Stream the screen to HLS or RTMP

Tags: android, screen, rtmp, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I've been recording the screen on Android using **MediaProjection API** and I'd like to live stream to my server. I've tried **MediaRecorder** with **ParcelFileDescriptor**, but nothing, also **MediaCodec**.

The best I could do was streaming to a RTMP server, using **ImageReader**, generating RGBA frames and converting to YUV before streaming, but this results in a very low *FPS*, since the conversion takes time and the ImageReader itself generates only a few fps.

- How can I stream while recording the screen?
  (Youtube Gaming App does it)

Comment: I'll admit that I don't understand a lot of what you are talking about but I'm going to take a stab in the dark. Sorry if I'm way off base. However, have you tried [Vysor](http://www.vysor.io/)?

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell Yes, however by live streaming I mean over the web, wireless, direct to a server, where it can be handled to be seen live by other people on a given url. It could be HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) or using Real Time Messaging Protocol (RTMP). It is somehow easy doing this using the camera, but very tricky using the screen recordings with MediaProjection API. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: YouTube Gaming app for Android, at least the newest version, offers ability to live stream your Android screen. Might be useful to ask YouTube developers for tips ;). http://techcrunch.com/2015/10/15/youtube-gaming-adds-mobile-streaming-and-twitch-like-features/

Comment: Colorspace conversion can be done many times faster in optimized assembly code than with Java.You can find some reference implementations in ffmpeg, but the license may be a problem for you.

Comment: @vipw I've already tried using ffmpeg with libstagefright as well, the result is better but not enough (25+ fps), I'm currently trying different approaches that not necessarily requires color conversion.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hello @ArthurAlves, I am facing the same issue. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?